# Java simple string print

Tags: java, string

Is there a more computationally-efficient way to write a simple constant string than this:

```
private void parseLabel(FileOutputStream asciiout) {
    asciiout.write(new String("Label: ").getBytes());
}
```

Seems that the alternative would be to allocate a byte array, put the string in the byte array, and then print the byte array...thought there would be something more direct.

Comment: You can avoid a string creation: `asciiout.write("Label: ".getBytes());`

Comment: I have good memories of my 486dx2-66. It had a turbo button and I could download games from a BBS :-)

Comment: cache those bytes instead of creating String instance everytime

Comment: Depends on the use case, and it's also worth questioning whether or not you need this to be more efficient. Premature optimization is evil

Comment: The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet.

Comment: All valid comments. @Leo, Yes, 486-DX2-66 was my first computer.  Remember lordsoth.happypuppy.org?

Comment: @486DX2-66 unfortunately not... but I do remember stunts :-)

Comment: Kids. My first computer was a Commodore 64, and I still have it. Get off my lawn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void parseLabel(FileOutputStream asciiout) {
    asciiout.write("Label: ".getBytes());
}
```